# Trying to use glossaries with isov2

Tags: sectioning, glossaries

When trying to use `\usepackage[section=sclause]{glossaries}` I get the following error:

```
Package xkeyval Error: value `sclause' is not allowed.

See the xkeyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.242 \setglossarysection{sclause}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

What is the easiest way to fix this?  A no heading option like `section=none` will also be useful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimum working sample using `\renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{}`
 as suggested in another thread:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{isov2}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[toc,acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{accreditation}{name={accreditation},
    description={procedure by which an authoritative 
    body gives formal recognition that a body or person is
    competent to carry out specific tasks [ISO/IEC Guide 2]}}
\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name=latex,
    description={Is a mark up language specially suited 
    for scientific documents \newline [Latexbook]}
}
\newacronym{dc}{d.c.}{direct current}
\newacronym{ac}{a.c.}{alternating current}
\newacronym{DC}{DC}{direct current, d.c. is preferred}
\newacronym{AC}{AC}{alternating current, a.c. is preferred}
\begin{document}


\clause{Terms, definitions and abbreviations}
\renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{}
\glsaddall
\sclause{Terms and definitions}
\printglossary
\sclause{Abbreviations}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\clause{Section}
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```